# Generated COM method lacks 'out' keyword on a parameter

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm trying to use the [Image Mastering API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_imapi/) from C# but some methods lack the `out` keyword and therefore fail to execute.

I generated the interop code by doing the following:

- References, Add Reference
- COM, Type Libraries
- Microsoft IMAPI2 Base Functionality

It worked correctly until I hit a wall, here's the code I'm currently using:

```
using System;
using IMAPI2;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var master2 = new MsftDiscMaster2();

            var recorder2 = new MsftDiscRecorder2();

            var recorderUniqueId = master2[0];

            Console.WriteLine(recorderUniqueId);

            recorder2.InitializeDiscRecorder(recorderUniqueId);

            var recorder2Ex = (IDiscRecorder2Ex)recorder2;

            // this fails as pointer should be an 'out' parameter

            // System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

            var discInformation = new IntPtr();

            recorder2Ex.GetDiscInformation(discInformation, out var byteSize);
        }
    }
}
```

The original signature for [IDiscRecorder2Ex::GetDiscInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imapi2/nf-imapi2-idiscrecorder2ex-getdiscinformation):

```
HRESULT GetDiscInformation(
  [out] BYTE                          **discInformation,
  [out] ULONG_IMAPI2_DISC_INFORMATION *byteSize
);
```

The signature that was generated by Visual Studio:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
void GetDiscInformation([Out] IntPtr discInformation, out uint byteSize);
```

I suppose that coding the interfaces manually would work but it's a huge task...

**Question:**

Is there a way to get Visual Studio generating the correct signature?

Comment: `out uint byteSize` looks correct for that signature. You need to pass for `discInformation` a pointer to an `IntPtr` variable, which will receive a pointer to the array, the size of which is received in `byteSize`. In other words, you need to do something like `unsafe { GetDiscInformation(&discInformation, out byteSize); }`

Comment: Works amazingly well, please post an answer so I can accept it and upvote you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is intended to return a pointer to an array, and a size, and both of these results come through `out` parameters. The `discInformation` parameter is double-indirected: it points to a location which stores a pointer to the start of the array being returned.

Technically speaking, I think this could have been translated as

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
void GetDiscInformation(
  [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out byte[] discInformation,
  [Out] out uint byteSize);
```

Then you can just do

```cs
GetDiscInformation(out var discInformation, out var byteSize);
```

However, the type library converter has not done this. So you need to marshal the array yourself. It looks like you simply aren't doing this correctly. :

```cs
byte[] discInformation;
unsafe
{
    var di = new IntPtr();
    recorder2Ex.GetDiscInformation((IntPtr)&di, out var byteSize);
    discInformation = new byte[byteSize];
    Marshal.Copy(di, discInformation, 0, byteSize);
}
```